# Ubuntu 16 installation failed on Odys Winbook 14 - [Errho 30] Read-only file system

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb

I have a Odys Winbook 14 with a preinstalled Windows 10. I booted Ubuntu via USB boot disk into the USB live session. When trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS ... at the step 'Who are you?' ... I get the following installation error:

```
The installer encountered copying files to the hard disk:

[Errho 30] Read-only file system: '/target/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/pvrusb2'

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, ... clean lens, ... chech if old and need replacement, ... move cooler environment.
```

How can I install it properly?

When I open GParted ... I get a warning saying:

The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

That's my setup:

[image]

Comment: Did you verify the iso download?  (ie. checksum) - it says that is a possible cause (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The checksum test ... $ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK ... gives me ... ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso: OK ... so I assume its ok. What else could it be?